# Only allow Numbers in input Tag without Javascript

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, input

I am fairly new. I am creating a webpage that ask a user for their ID. I want it to be a required field and only allow numbers.  I appreciate if you lead me in the correct direction. this is what I have so far.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
  <title>Search</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div>
  <table align="center">
    <tr>
        <td class="label">
            Enter ID:
        </td>
         <td>
            <input type="text" name="UserId" id="UserId" />
        </td>
     </tr>
   </table>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: off the topic: Without JavaScript !!! any specific reasons? I'd love to see the solution though...

Comment: There is no reason. I looked online and it only give me solution with javascript.  It seems to me that its much simpler if I just do it in html.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Though it's probably suggested to get some heavier validation via JS or on the server, HTML5 [does support this](http://www.pageresource.com/html5/input-validation-tutorial/) via the pattern attribute.

```
<input type= "text" name= "name" pattern= "[0-9]"  title= "Title"/>
```

Comment: Just tried this to no avail :( any chance you could take a peek here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17999067/how-to-force-only-numbers-in-a-input-without-javascript

Comment: @Davo This is an HTML5 attribute, so it won't work on older IE's without some polyfill. You can check for support here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input

Comment: @Brain, I apologize, I misread your answer, it does work in a way you described, I thought it was supposed to work like, when u hit keyboard button that is not number it just wont type anything(like equivalent of returning false in js), so, it did not work that way, but it was not what u had written. Thanks. P.S. I removed my comment :)

Comment: @Davo No problem. To do *that* keyboard blocking, you can see this code here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19966612/830111

Comment: Not to be overly pedantic but the OP used the word "numbers" (plural). Doesn't the pattern on this answer allow only a single digit? This will also not allow negative numbers or decimal places. You may want to look here for a more thorough answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16460773/regex-validate-negative-and-positive-decimal-numbers/16461060

Comment: If the field is required, update the `pattern` attribute to include regex's "one or more" quantifier (`[0-9+]`). If optional, you can use "zero or more" (`[0-9*]`). If you need to allow for decimals, leverage the `step` attribute: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number#step

Answer (score 24):

Try this with the + after [0-9]:

```
input type="text" pattern="[0-9]+" title="number only"
```

Comment: What's the use of +?

Comment: @Niby Because without +  accept only one number if you have some validation!

Answer (score 14):

Of course, you can't fully rely on the **client-side** (javascript) **validation**, but that's not a reason to avoid it completely. With or without it, you have to do the **server-side validation** anyway (since the client can **disable javascript**). And that's just what you're left with, due to your non-javascript solution constraint.

So, after a submit, if the field value doesn't pass the **server-side validation**, the client should end up on the very same page, with additional **error message** specifying the requested **value format**. You also should provide the value format information **beforehands**, e.g. as a tool-tip hint (`title` attribute).

There's most certainly no passive client-side validation mechanism existing in HTML 4 / XHTML.

On the other hand, in **HTML 5** you have two options:

- input of type [**`number`**](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_input_types.asp):

  ```
  <input type="number" min="xxx" max="yyy" title="Format: 3 digits" />
  ```

  – only validates the range – if user enters a non-number, an **empty value** is submitted

  – the field visual is enhanced with increment / decrement controls (browser dependent)
- the [**`pattern`**](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_input_pattern.asp) attribute:

  ```
  <input type="text" pattern="[0-9]{3}" title="Format: 3 digits" />
  <input type="text" pattern="\d{3}" title="Format: 3 digits" />
  ```

  – this gives you a full contorl over the format (anything you can specify by [**regular expression**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp))

  – no visual difference / enhancement

But here you still rely on **browser capabilities**, so do a server-side validation in either case.

Comment: Thank You so basically, I need java script? Will do thank you

Comment: Wait a minute. HTML5 seems to provide some improvements. Will report in a while.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
<input type="number" name="amount" pattern="^[0-9]+[0-9]*$"/>
```