# Get incorrect value from input type='number'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

There is a field for input and i need to get the string that is entered into it.

```js
$("#test").on("change", function(){
  console.log($(this).val());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='number' id="test">
```

It's works. But, if i copy/paste incorrect string (for example: "123231,3232.00") to input, console.log return empty string. How i get pasted value?

Comment: You can't. A "number" `<input>` won't give you a value if the value does not work when interpreted as a number. (In browsers that really support "number" input fields, of course.)

Comment: Probably related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17999067/how-to-force-only-numbers-in-a-input-without-javascript

Comment: Chrome won't even let me paste the comma in there…

Comment: Josh Lee, Try copy and past string "123231,3232.00"

Answer (score 0):

> > > You have used the **type** attribute in the HTML input element with it's value **number**. The input must be **number** with this attribute value.

```
        type='number' in <input type='number' id="test">
```

So,If you will enter values in input **other than numbers**, it will give you empty result.
Either remove the **type attribute** from Input Element or you can use the proper input values.

Example:
1) Input value: **12354**, Result will be **12345** (Correct with above case)
2) Input value: **"12345"**, Result will be empty (**due to type attribute in input element**)

You can check here and use the attribute value according to need: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp