# Number input field: detect special cases "+" and "-"

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

While using some javascript, I have noticed that if there is a "-" (or "+") in a number input field, if I call the `.value` function on it, the value returned will be "" (undefined)!

I can understand where it came from: this way, the value returned will be a consistent number all the time, function like this that returns the *string* "-" (or "+") will cause troubles.

However, in my implementation, I want to detect this scenario. **Is there any way that I can differentiate the inputs "" (undefined) and "-" (or "+") in an `<input type="number"/>` field using JavaScript? maybe with something with jQuery instead?**

Below you can see a small example of the scenario I'm talking about.
Thanks in advance!

```js
function updatevaluefield() {
  value_span = document.getElementById("value_field");
  input = document.getElementById("input");
  
  value_span.innerHTML = input.value;

}

function updateinputvalue() {
  input = document.getElementById("input");
  input.value = "-";
  
  updatevaluefield();
}
```

```html
<input id="input" type="number" value="123"/>
<button onclick="updateinputvalue()">Set input field to "-"</button><br/>

<br/><br/>

The value of the input field is: <span id="value_field"></span> <br/>
<button onclick="updatevaluefield()">Show value (update)</button>
```

Comment: Number inputs [reject non numerical entities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number). You can set the number to be negative, but you can't have other characters like - or +. I'd use a text input and add in the functionality you're looking for yourself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Only allow Numbers in input Tag without Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12533508/only-allow-numbers-in-input-tag-without-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following.

```js
function updatevaluefield() {
  var value_span = document.getElementById("value_field");
  var input = document.getElementById("input");
  value_span.innerHTML = input.value;
}

function updateinputvalue() {
  var input = document.getElementById("input");
  console.log(typeof input.value, input.value);
  var n = parseInt(input.value);
  if (n > 0) {
    n = 0 - n;
  } else if(n < 0) {
    n = Math.abs(n);
  }
  input.value = n;
  updatevaluefield();
}
```

```html
<input id="input" type="number" value="123" />
<button onclick="updateinputvalue()">Toggle Input</button><br/>

<br/><br/> The value of the input field is: <span id="value_field"></span> <br/>
<button onclick="updatevaluefield()">Show value (update)</button>
```

Input elements return a String type, even if they are `type='number'` with HTML5. So if we cast it back to an integer, we can perform Math on it better. This method also prevents the User from passing in strange characters.

`parseInt()` will treat "1" and "-1" as expected. `1` and `-1` respectively.

```js
console.log(parseInt("0123"));
console.log(parseInt("-123"));
console.log(parseInt("+123"));
```